# How would I encrypt password

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to encrypt the password of my users using BCryptPasswordEncoder and I get this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: `Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'` defined in class path resource. I will want your help

This is my Controller:

```
    @Autowired
    private JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager;

    @Autowired
    private AgentRepository agentRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView register(){

        return new ModelAndView("registration","user", new UserRegistration());
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processRegister(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistration userRegistrationObject) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userRegistrationObject.getPassword());

        User user = new User(userRegistrationObject.getUsername(), encodedPassword, authorities);
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/welcome");
    }


        // Create a new Agent

    @PostMapping("/searchouse/agent")
    public Agent createAgent(@Valid @RequestBody Agent agent) {

        Agent agent2 = agentRepository.creationAgent(agent.getUserName());
        if (agent2 == null) {
            return agentRepository.save(agent);}
            else{
             throw new RessourcesNotFoundException("Cet username existe déjà");
            }
        }



    //Update logement

    @PutMapping("/searchouse/agent/{id}")

    public  Agent updateAgent(@PathVariable(value="id") Long Id,
                                    @Valid @RequestBody Agent agentDetails){

        Agent agent = agentRepository.findById(Id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Agent","id", Id));

        agent.setNom(agentDetails.getNom());
        agent.setPrenom(agentDetails.getPrenom());
        agent.setMail(agentDetails.getMail());
        agent.setSociete(agentDetails.getSociete());
        agent.setPsswd(agentDetails.getPsswd());
        agent.setTelephone(agentDetails.getTelephone());``
        agent.setUserName(agentDetails.getUserName());
        agent.setVille(agentDetails.getVille());

        Agent updateAgent =agentRepository.save(agent);

        return updateAgent;
    }


    @GetMapping("/searchouse/agent/{id}")
    public Agent getAgentById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long Id) {
        return agentRepository.findById(Id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Agent","id",Id));
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchouse/agent/{id}/logements")
    public List<Logement> retrieveAllLogement(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long Id) {
        Agent agent = getAgentById(Id);
        return agent.getLogements();
    }


    @PostMapping("/searchouse/connexion")

    public Agent connexion(@Valid @RequestParam String name,String psswd){
        return agentRepository.connexionAgent(name, psswd);
    }

    // Delete a Agent
    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long Id) {
        Agent agent = agentRepository.findById(Id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Agent", "id", Id));

        agentRepository.delete(agent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }



}
```

StackTrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.searchhouse.searchhouse.SearchhouseApplication.main(SearchhouseApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.<init>(FilterComparator.java:88) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.<init>(HttpSecurity.java:126) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:206) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.searchhouse.searchhouse.configuration.SpringSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fbd17913.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9868a481.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9868a481$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e18f73f8.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9868a481.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @Shubh please don't format a stacktrace as mention this makes it unreadable. Format it as code

Comment: @Shubh I reformatted it now it looks usable

Comment: Can you please show SpringSecurityConfig

Comment: `No class def found error` your  spring security class is present at compile time but not at runtime

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file, looks like incorrect dependency setup.

Comment: Class was added in Spring Sec 5.1 according to the docs. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.html You most likely have an older version on the runtime classpath. Look in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of deployed application.